# Adding elapsed TimeInterval to Date()

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to add the elapsed time to a Date() object (its for the resume button of a timed operation).

Below is the resume portion of the code responsible for calculating the altered `startDate`. I'm expecting it to add the `elapsed` `TimeInterval` to `startDate`.

This is the code:

```
print(startDate)
let elapsed = resumeTime - startDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
print(elapsed)
startDate.addTimeInterval(elapsed)
print(startDate)
```

This is the output when I paused the timer for about 3 seconds after about 2 minutes of runtime.

Output:

```
2016-11-17 08:24:15 +0000
110.831687986851
2016-11-17 08:26:06 +0000
```

The second printed date should be more like:

```
2016-11-17 08:24:18 +0000
```

The definition for `addTimeInterval` is:

> Add a TimeInterval to this Date.

Isn't this exactly what I want? Am I interpreting this incorrectly?

Note, `resumeTime` is defined when the pause button is tapped. It is set like this:

```
resumeTime = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the output of `elapsed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is the output when I paused the timer for about 3 seconds after about 2 minutes of runtime.

Although, your `elapsed` time is  2 min.

Make sure that you start elapsed in the right place, also make sure that this line generates the desired timestamp:

```
resumeTime = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
```

Here is example of code very similar to yours, `addTimeInterval` does work well.

```
let resume = Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate + 2

print(startDate)
let elapsed = resume - startDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
print(elapsed)
startDate.addTimeInterval(elapsed)
print(startDate)
```

**Output**

```
2016-11-17 08:53:34 +0000
2.00815904140472
2016-11-17 08:53:36 +0000
```

Comment: I figured it out after reading your answer, see the answer I added. I up-voted you because it was nearly what I wanted. I shouldn't have been using `startDate`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the mistake in your code is that you never set the `startDate` again, so your `elapsed` calculation is always based on when the app first ran, not the time elapsed since the last time you paused.